# C: linked lists - function "insert first" is not working as expected

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, malloc

In the following Code you can see a basic integer-linked list realized with pointers in C.
I have written two different functions for inserting a new int-val in the front of the list.
I thought that these 2 functions would be equivalent but as the output shows they are not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _IntlistElem* Intlist;
typedef struct _IntlistElem {int val; Intlist next;} IntlistElem;

Intlist insertfirst(int val, Intlist list) {
    Intlist new = malloc(sizeof(IntlistElem));
    new->val = val;
    new->next = list;

    return new;
}

Intlist insertfirstAlternative(int val, Intlist list) {
    IntlistElem new = {val, list};
    Intlist head = &new;

    return head;
}

void print(Intlist l){
    while (l!=NULL){
        printf("%d\n", l->val);
        l = l->next;
    }
printf("_____\n");
}

int main(){
    Intlist ls = NULL;
    ls = insertfirst(2, ls);
    ls = insertfirst(1, ls);
    print(ls);

    Intlist lsAlt = NULL;
    lsAlt = insertfirstAlternative(2, lsAlt);
    lsAlt = insertfirstAlternative(1, lsAlt);
    print(lsAlt);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
_____
1
1
...
```

My questions are:
1.
Why is the print-function not terminating? (after calling the alternative function)
2.
Why are these 2 "insertfirst"-functions not equivalent as I expected?
What is the difference between these functions?

I am looking forward to your answers. :)

Comment: You should urgently learn how to use the debugger to inspect your code flow and current variable values when stepping through line by line.

Comment: `Intlist head = &new;` : `new` is local auto variable. It is not valid outside the scope.

Comment: This code doesn't compile with warning flags (gcc's are: -Wall -Werror -Wextra). I encourage you to use them next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `insertfirstAlternative` returns a pointer to `head`. That variable's lifetime ends at return from the function. So, it returns an invalid pointer value.

> The value of a pointer becomes indeterminate when the object it points to reaches the end of its lifetime.

Anything could happen.

In your case, the second time you invoke the function, the second `head` is created at the same address as the first, so the `next` pointer points to the same object. Hence the endless loop.

Comment: First of all thank you. But how is it possible that the allocated IntlistElem the variable "new" points too is staying alive after "insertfirst" has terminated.

Comment: It does not stay alive. For efficiency reasons, the memory is not cleared and reading from its address (through your dangling pointer) kind-of works. But this is just by chance. If you call other functions in between, the memory will probably be reused and overwritten.

Comment: Okay thank you. So this means there is no way for a linked list to be "safe" ?

Comment: @CptCook They are if you allocate them on the heap (malloc)